# Webpack file loader 'Unexpected character' error production only

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader, survivejs

I have been trying many different configurations but I now feel like I have been staring at this problem for too long and can't figure it out anymore. I am trying to use webpack `file-loader` for simple images, while a normal configuration works like a charm in dev, I encounter the error mentioned in the title any time I run `npm run start` with SSR. To provide additional info here are the rules in my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/ClientApp.jsx'
  ],
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/public/'),
    publicPath: '/public/',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'server') {
  config.entry = './src/ClientApp.jsx';
  config.devtool = false;
  config.plugins = [];
}

module.exports = config;
```

Here are me dependencies:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack -d",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.{js,jsx} --quiet",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-addons-perf": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.3",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "prettier": "^1.5.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
```

Just for completion my `public` folder is structured like this `public/js` and `public/images`, and webpack properly outputs the images in this folder. I feel like I made a distraction error somewhere, so please let me know if you need any additional info to help me figure this out. This is a brand new setup so every package is at its latest version.

**EDIT**

I actually noticed that unless I run `webpack -p` first (which creates the `public/images` folder with the used images inside), in dev mode the console tells me it can't find any image, the dev build doesn't throw any error but there's something off with the paths, I can only make it work if I do not specify any path. In production this configuration "works" but I get the `Unexpected character` error.

Comment: can you post your package.json dependencies and devDependencies.  Also are you running webpack on the production machine, or are you building and pushing a built file to production to be ran?

Comment: I'll post the dependencies in a minute, but I'm just running npm start locally and simulating a production environment. I build then run npm start and I get the unexpected character error.

Comment: @thomasmeadows I added my dependencies as well

Comment: can you show your file structure, with the unexpected character filename, and your package.json scripts might help and the rest of your webpack file.

Comment: also I think file-loader's public path should be /images not /js/. /js/ implies your image urls are going to be at www.yourdomain.com/js/<images>

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I removed all subfolders and I am now outputting everything in `/public`, I updated the question with more info. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: you could try instead of doing webpack -p .   In your plugins array for production add

new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({mangle: false});  -p is simply a shortcut to add uglification.

Comment: Sure thanks, although that doesn't help solving the images issue.

Comment: If that didnt help, I would need more info about the error/problem that is occurring because everything else looks fine in your configuration and package.json.   Usually that solves problems when there is a discrepancy between production and dev builds.

Comment: Alright I'll do this, I will create a smaller very basic version of what I have now and see if the file loader works, then go from there until I find out if it's the loader or something else conflicting. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Nothing still no luck, I will file an issue directly in the repo at this point.

Comment: I missed a key detail, I am doing SSR. So it boils down to babel trying to transpile images as js files I guess, I am trying a `transform-assets` babel plugin now which almost solves this issue.